# How to implement a Lisp macro system?

Tags: clojure, macros, lisp

I've implemented my own Lisp on top of node.js, I can run s-expressions like this:

```
(assert (= 3 (+ 1 2)))

(def even? (fn [n] (= 0 (bit-and n 1))))

(assert (even? 4))
(assert (= false (even? 5)))
```

Now I would like to add macros - the `defmacro` function - but this is where I'm stuck. I'm wondering how macro systems are implemented in other Lisps but I couldn't find many pointers (apart from [this](http://www.reddit.com/comments/6ehu9/ask_reddit_tutorial_for_writing_a_lisp_interpreter) and [this](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?LispMacro)).

I've looked at the Clojure macro system - the Lisp I'm most familiar with - but that seemed too complicated and I couldn't find additional clues that I can readily apply (Clojure macros ultimately compile to byte code which doesn't apply to javascript, also I couldn't make sense of the `macroexpand1` function.)

So my question is: given a Lisp implementation without macros but with an AST, how does one add a macro system like Clojure's macro system? Can this macro system be implemented in Lisp, or does it require extra features in the implementation in the host language?

One additional remark: I haven't implemented `quote` (`'`) yet because I couldn't figure out what kind of values should be in the returned list. Should it contain AST elements or objects like `Symbol` and `Keyword` (the latter being the case for Clojure)?

Answer (score 17):

All a macro does is take unevaluated forms as parameters and perform replacement on its body. The trick to implementation a macro system is to tell your compiler to be [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Put in another way, when the compiler encounters a function, it first evaluates its formal parameter list, yields the results and passes them to the function. When the compiler finds a macro, it passes the arguments *unevaluated* to the body, then performs any computation the body requests, and finally replaces itself with the result of those.

For instance, lets say you have a function:

```
(defun print-3-f (x) (progn (princ x) (princ x) (princ x)))
```

and a macro:

```
(defmacro print-3-m (x) `(progn (princ ,x) (princ ,x) (princ ,x)))
```

Then you can see the difference straight away:

```
CL-USER> (print-3-f (rand))
* 234
* 234
* 234

CL-USER> (print-3-m (rand))
* 24
* 642
* 85
```

To understand why this is, you need to, in a manner of speaking, run the compiler in your head.

When Lisp comes across the function, it builds a tree in which `(rand)` is first evaluated and the result passed to the function, which prints said result three times.

On the other hand, when Lisp comes across the macro, it passes the form `(rand)` *untouched* to the body, which returns a quoted list where `x` is replaced by `(rand)`, yielding:

```
(progn (princ (rand)) (princ (rand)) (princ (rand)))
```

and replacing the macro call for this new form.

[Here](http://linuxfinances.info/info/macros.html) you will find vast amounts of documentation regarding macros in a variety of languages, including Lisp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can summarize your answer as follows:

For `defun`: 1) evaluate AST (returns javascript `function` objects) 2) execute the javascripts functions 3) pass the resulting values as arguments to the lisp function. This is what I'm already doing.

For `defmacro`: 1) idem 2) skip 3) pass the javascript functions as arguments to the macro. The result that is returned by ` should then be AST elements that should be evaluated and executed.

This leaves one question unanswered: what should `quote` return? Should it be a list of AST elements or javascript functions and other objs?

Comment: (quote ...) returns a list of "stuff", where "stuff" is in a form that may be later evaluated. The beauty of lisp is that its list representation is the same as the AST representation, so returning a list or an AST are equivalent.

Comment: That a macro does not evaluate its arguments seems to be a side effect of its nature, rather than its main defining property, to me.

Answer (score 7):

This is from Peter Norvig's [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming](http://norvig.com/paip.html) - an essential tome for any LISP programmers bookshelf.

He assumes you're implementing an Interpreted language, and provides the example of a Scheme Interpreter running in LISP.

[The following two examples here](http://norvig.com/paip/interp1.lisp) show how he adds macros to the primary `eval` function (`interp`)

Here is the function for interpreting an S-expression prior to dealing with macros:

```
(defun interp (x &optional env)
  "Interpret (evaluate) the expression x in the environment env."
  (cond
    ((symbolp x) (get-var x env))
    ((atom x) x)
    ((case (first x)
       (QUOTE  (second x))
       (BEGIN  (last1 (mapcar #'(lambda (y) (interp y env))
                              (rest x))))
       (SET!   (set-var! (second x) (interp (third x) env) env))
       (IF     (if (interp (second x) env)
                   (interp (third x) env)
                   (interp (fourth x) env)))
       (LAMBDA (let ((parms (second x))
                     (code (maybe-add 'begin (rest2 x))))
                 #'(lambda (&rest args)
                     (interp code (extend-env parms args env)))))
       (t      ;; a procedure application
               (apply (interp (first x) env)
                      (mapcar #'(lambda (v) (interp v env))
                              (rest x))))))))
```

And here it is after a macro evaluation has been added (child methods have been in the reference link for clarity

```
(defun interp (x &optional env)
  "Interpret (evaluate) the expression x in the environment env.
  This version handles macros."
  (cond
    ((symbolp x) (get-var x env))
    ((atom x) x)

    ((scheme-macro (first x))              
     (interp (scheme-macro-expand x) env)) 

    ((case (first x)
       (QUOTE  (second x))
       (BEGIN  (last1 (mapcar #'(lambda (y) (interp y env))
                              (rest x))))
       (SET!   (set-var! (second x) (interp (third x) env) env))
       (IF     (if (interp (second x) env)
                   (interp (third x) env)
                   (interp (fourth x) env)))
       (LAMBDA (let ((parms (second x))
                     (code (maybe-add 'begin (rest2 x))))
                 #'(lambda (&rest args)
                     (interp code (extend-env parms args env)))))
       (t      ;; a procedure application
               (apply (interp (first x) env)
                      (mapcar #'(lambda (v) (interp v env))
                              (rest x))))))))
```

It is interesting to note that the opening Chapter of [Christian Queinnec's](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/Queinnec.html) [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) has a very similar function, he calls it `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a macro-expansion phase in your evaluation chain:

```
text-input -> read -> macroexpand -> compile -> load
```

Note that the macro expansion should be recursive (macroexpand until nothing macroexpandable is left).

Your environments need the ability to "hold" macro-expansion functions that can be looked up by name in this phase.  Note that `defmacro` is a macro itself in Common Lisp, which sets up the right calls to associate the name with the macro expansion function in that environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand correctly the macroexpand function converts a macro and its arguments into macro-free lisp code. Correct?

Comment: Your description is somewhat imprecise, but I think that you have the right idea. :)

Comment: Ok, I've made the mental click. I'm refactoring my implementation as follows: 1/ read user code, convert to lists containing AstSymbol, AstKeyword, AstString, AstInteger, ... and of course other lists; 2/ convert library macros (`defmacro`) to AST; 3/ traverse user AST looking for macros (`defmacro`); 4/ the actual macroexpand phase: replace AST elements that call macros (detect macro calls here) with the AST elements of the macro (replace macro arguments with relevant user AST elements); 5/ AST should now be macro-free, interpret. I found [this](http://bit.ly/CpcCU) very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.meta-alternative.net/pseudoArc.zip) example. It's a toy implementation of an Arc-like compiler, with a decent macro support.

Comment: The link is broken.  Can you find it somewhere else?