# Given the following LISP eval function - what is required to add defmacro?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, eval

Given the following [definition](http://lib.store.yahoo.net/lib/paulgraham/jmc.lisp) of the LISP eval function - what is required to add the `defmacro` function? (Or even just evaluate a macro)

```
(defun null. (x)
      (eq x '()))

(defun and. (x y)
  (cond (x (cond (y 't) ('t '())))
        ('t '())))

(defun not. (x)
  (cond (x '())
        ('t 't)))

(defun append. (x y)
  (cond ((null. x) y)
        ('t (cons (car x) (append. (cdr x) y)))))

(defun list. (x y)
  (cons x (cons y '())))

(defun pair. (x y)
  (cond ((and. (null. x) (null. y)) '())
        ((and. (not. (atom x)) (not. (atom y)))
         (cons (list. (car x) (car y))
               (pair. (cdr x) (cdr y))))))

(defun assoc. (x y)
  (cond ((eq (caar y) x) (cadar y))
        ('t (assoc. x (cdr y)))))

(defun eval. (e a)
  (cond
    ((atom e) (assoc. e a))
    ((atom (car e))
     (cond
       ((eq (car e) 'quote) (cadr e))
       ((eq (car e) 'atom)  (atom   (eval. (cadr e) a)))
       ((eq (car e) 'eq)    (eq     (eval. (cadr e) a)
                                    (eval. (caddr e) a)))
       ((eq (car e) 'car)   (car    (eval. (cadr e) a)))
       ((eq (car e) 'cdr)   (cdr    (eval. (cadr e) a)))
       ((eq (car e) 'cons)  (cons   (eval. (cadr e) a)
                                    (eval. (caddr e) a)))
       ((eq (car e) 'cond)  (evcon. (cdr e) a))
       ('t (eval. (cons (assoc. (car e) a)
                        (cdr e))
                  a))))
    ((eq (caar e) 'label)
     (eval. (cons (caddar e) (cdr e))
            (cons (list. (cadar e) (car e)) a)))
    ((eq (caar e) 'lambda)
     (eval. (caddar e)
            (append. (pair. (cadar e) (evlis. (cdr e) a))
                     a)))))

(defun evcon. (c a)
  (cond ((eval. (caar c) a)
         (eval. (cadar c) a))
        ('t (evcon. (cdr c) a))))

(defun evlis. (m a)
  (cond ((null. m) '())
        ('t (cons (eval.  (car m) a)
                  (evlis. (cdr m) a)))))


(eval '(car '(a a)) )
```

Comment: This is another [way to approach the macro implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465868/how-to-implement-a-lisp-macro-system/10363040#10363040)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The representation of an anonymous macro is by convention a list of the form `(macro lambda ...)`.  Try evaling these in your favorite Lisp interpreter (tested in Emacs):

**>** (defmacro triple (x) `(+ ,x ,x ,x))

*triple*

**>** (symbol-function 'triple)

*(macro lambda (x) (\` (+ (\, x) (\, x) (\, x))))*

Although things don't work that way in Emacs, the only thing left to do is to give the adequate semantics to such a form. That is, when `eval.` sees `((macro lambda (x) EXPR) FORM)`, it must

1. Replace every occurence of `x` in `FORM` with `EXPR` **without** evaluating `EXPR` first (as opposed to what happens in a function call);
2. `eval.` the result of above.

You can achieve this by adding a clause to the outermost `cond` in `eval.` that deals with the `((macro lambda ...) ...)` case. Here is a crude prototype:

```
((eq (caar e) 'macro)
     (cond
      ((eq (cadar e) 'lambda)
       (eval. (eval. (car (cdddar e))
                     (cons (list. (car (caddar e)) (cadr e)) a))
              a))))
```

This code only works for single-argument macros. Fixing that involves writing an auxiliary function `substlis.` that works like `evlis.` but without looping to `eval.`; that is  left as an exercise to the reader :-)

To test, define `cadr.` as a macro thusly:

```
(defmacro cadr. (x)
  (list. 'car (list. 'cdr x)))
```

After this you would have

**>** (symbol-function 'cadr.)

*(macro lambda (x) (list. (quote car) (list. (quote cdr) x)))*

You can construct a form that applies this `(macro lambda ...)` to an expression, and eval that construction within a context that contains a definition for `list.` (because it is not considered primitive by the `eval.` interpreter).  For instance,

```
(let ((e '((macro lambda (x) (list (quote car) (list (quote cdr) x)))
           (cons (quote x) (cons (quote y) nil))))
      (bindings `((list ,(symbol-function 'list.)))))
  (eval. e bindings))
```

*y*

Tada!

Comment: Thanks @DomQ - but the two LISP environments I tried your solution in give a stackoverflow. Is it possible there is a problem in your solution?

Comment: There's a bug in "assoc." causing the overflow, try evaling (assoc. 'x nil). You can fix it by adding a clause to "assoc."'s cond block that reads: ((null. y) '()) . I emailed Paul Graham about this, he says that this is not a bug, as the original author John McCarthy didn't care about incorrect programs (ie those that reference free variables in "eval.").  Anyway, it might be that the stack overflow you observe is but a symptom of another issue. Try with http://paste.lisp.org/+2GC7 (contains both the "assoc." fix and my solution to your question; tested with Emacs 22 and librep.sf.net).

Answer (score 3):

This is also quite good:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120702032624/http://jlongster.com/2012/02/18/its-not-about-macros-its-about-read.html

"You can implement a macro system in 30 lines of Lisp. All you need is read, and it's easy."
https://gist.github.com/1712455