# Does adding f-exprs simplify the implementation of macros from fundamental expressions in LISP?

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp, scheme

[This guy](http://axisofeval.blogspot.com/2011/07/meaning-of-forms.html) reckons that adding fexprs to LISP dramatically simplifies the implementation of the language in scheme.

[Here we see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683388/given-the-following-lisp-eval-function-what-is-required-to-add-defmacro) how macros would be implemented using MacCarthy's LISP.

My question is - does adding f-exprs simplify the implementation of macros in LISP?

Comment: The important thing about lisp is abstraction, not implementation. The need for simplicity of the implementation is mostly irrelevant next to the need for simplicity of the abstraction. Take eval, you can fit its definition on a blackboard, but the only thing its useful for is teaching you about one aspect of computation, namely recursively defining something in itself. The usefulness of that knowledge is much less than the usefulness of what eval enables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm that guy. :)

Fexprs, as in the Kernel language, dramatically simplify the language - [Kernel](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~jshutt/kernel.html) has only *three* built-ins: $define! (for adding a new binding to an environment), $if (the usual), and $vau (similar to lambda, but doesn't evaluate its arguments).

Furthermore, macros (fexprs) may be used as functions can - unlike current Lisps, where macros work separate from runtime. This makes the language more general.

That said, there are as of yet no real-world applications written in Kernel or another new Lisp with fexprs. This is an area of active tinkering by a handful of people.

Comment: I'm interested as I've always found the distinction between macros and functions to be a little too arbitrary. How easy would it be to add these (experimentally) to Clojure?

Comment: Probably very hard.  Fexprs require interpretation, as there are as of yet no known means to compile them efficiently. [This blog post](http://axisofeval.blogspot.com/2011/06/john-shutts-blog.html) contains pointers to LtU discussions where people talk about implementation issues.

Comment: Did I get it right that this approach is only suitable for interpretation?

Comment: @mikera there are [tweet](http://twitter.com/#!/fogus/status/128198563330134016) [statuses](http://twitter.com/#!/fogus/status/128208790989443072) indicating, that some kind of fexpr implementation may be on it's way to Clojure...